# Magento 2 : Save Customer Page Data Issue

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, customer

I created three custom field in customer account edit page and same field created in admin panel inside customer edit form.

But now, how to save data? I tried to override the `editPost.php` file and use this `$customer->setCustomAttribute('abc',$this->getRequest()->getParam('ABC'));`

This is not help in saving data and show undefine variable "customer" error.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: customer in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/xxx/xxx/Controller/Account/EditPost.php on line 140
```

Comment: create fields using custom attribute , so these value will save by model

Comment: how to create field by custom attribute in frontend. and i am using community edition, so there is no feature of creating customer attribute  in admin panel. i created that attribute by installdata.php

Comment: @sam: did you understood how to save additional data? I'm experiencing the same trouble. Thanks, Ale

Comment: @Ale, yes i understood. please see  my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created some custom field in customer account edit page, and i saved their value in database by editing editpost.php file.

1. Please don't change the default file, so first overide that file in your custom module
2. then in execute function , under try, put these code

suppose that i created one field "myname" on frontend in edit form, and one field "name" in admin panel edit form. in database, the column name is also should be "name"
then the code will be;

```
$customerCandidateDataObject->setCustomAttribute('name',$this->getRequest()->getParam('myname'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create customer attribute in `installer script` by following [this link.](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html)

These will help you in creating attribute for frontend.

Comment: i created custom attribute like this only.  and data is saved also in admin panel, my question is , on fronted , customer account information page, i created field, from there how to save the data?

Comment: you don't need to create fields in frontend , they will come with this code: `'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create','adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer'],
`

Comment: No it is not coming.  by this code it is coming only in admin panel